# Merging two datasets in D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple "plug-n-play" map template, that allows user to put a csv file with geoids and values and then see the values as a choropleth.

Right now I am merging two datasets  (map and values) using double loop, but wondering if there is any other option:

This chunk of code stays within the function that loads geodata (fresh_ctss) :

```
d3.csv("data/communities_pop.csv", function(error, comms)
          {
              csv = comms.map(function(d)
              {
                  //each d is one line of the csv file represented as a json object
                  // console.log("Label: " + d.CTLabel)
                  return {"community": d.community, "population" :d.population,"label": d.tract} ;
              })

              csv.forEach(function(d, i) {
                fresh_ctss.forEach(function(e, j) {
              if (d.label === e.properties.geoid) {
                  e.properties.community = parseInt(d.community)
                  e.properties.population = parseInt(d.population)
                  }
                })
              })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll definitely need two loops (or a nested loop) - the most optimal way would be to just limit how much iteration needs to happen. Right now, the first loop goes through every csv row. The following nested loop goes through every csv row (as new different object) and then, as many times as there are rows in the csv, through every item in `fresh_ctss`.

If you mapped the rows into an object instead of an array, you could iterate through the rows once (total) and then once through the elements of `fresh_ctss` (again, total). Code below assumes that there are no `tract` duplicates in `comms`:

```
all_comms = {}
comms.forEach(function(d) {
  all_comms[d.tract] = {"community": d.community, "population": d.population}
})
fresh_ctss.forEach(function(e) {
  comm = all_comms[e.properties.geoid]
  e.properties.community = parseInt(comm.community)
  e.properties.population = parseInt(comm.population)
}
```